# Base classes missing with Pydev interpreter and virtualenv

Tags: eclipse, interpreter, pydev, virtualenv

Ok, so if I create a brand new virtualenv, then hop into that environment, go into a python shell within that environment, and run 'import logging', for instance, it imports absolutely fine.  I can then start up eclipse, create a new interpreter based on the /bin/python in my virtualenv and if I open up a python console within eclipse, based on this new interpreter, I can run 'import logging' again without any problems.  I can create a project, with this new interpreter and create a sample file with nothing but

```
import logging
print asdf
```

I'll get an 'unresolved import' error with the line 'import logging'.  This can be resolved by adding in the system lib/pythonX.X directory (in my case /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6) to the interpreter configuration, but I'd be under the impression that this is counter-intuitive for what you'd want to be doing with eclipse and virtualenv.

I know the stuff that's in that lib/pythonX.X directory are pretty much nothing but the base classes, but if they should always be included, should they not just be included anyway?  Is this not against the way virtualenv setting up links to these very classes within it's own lib/pythonX.X directory?  Is adding the base python lib/pythonX.X directory to the eclipse interpreter the correct way to do this, or is there problems with doing this?

Am I getting confused by the whole setup, or is it actually confusing and I'm right to ask the question? Thanks for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just confusing... You really have to add the paths of the base interpreter when configuring the virtualenv interpreter in PyDev (i.e.: in the command line, when you start that interpreter and do an `import sys;print(sys.path)`, the folders of the base interpreter will probably be there, so, they also need to be in PyDev).